# How do I send a 2D array in a JSON structure?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I want to send 2D array in a JSON structure.

The overall structure I want is

```json
{
    "PED": {
        "fun": "enviarPedido",
        "txtUser":"123",
        "md5Passwd": "123",                          
        "arrArticulos": [
            [50,10,5,50],
            [51,9,6.5,58.5],
            [52,8,7,56],
            [53,7,8.5,59.5]
        ]
    }
}
```

I want the 2D array generated from the cursor data and put into this JSON Structure

```json
    "arrArticulos": [
        [50,10,5,50],
        [51,9,6.5,58.5],
        [52,8,7,56],
        [53,7,8.5,59.5]
    ]
```

What is the solution?

Comment: why dont you use gson https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: I tried I get the result as [{"itemid":4,"quantity":8.0,"price":10.0,"total":80.0},{"itemid":5,"quantity":8.0,"price":100.0,"total":800.0}] 

I dont want the tags of the values

Comment: @ Dhiraj Tayade as what?

Comment: I need this 
 "arrArticulos":[
    [4,8.0,10.0,80.0],
    [5,8.‌​0,100.0,800.0]
               ] 

I got  this 

"arrArticulos": [{"itemid":4,"quantity":8.0,"price":10.0,"total":80.0},{"itemid":5,"quantity":8.‌​0,"price":100.0,"total":800.0}]

Comment: Any reason you don't want the tags?  Your Java object isn't a basic array, it's a real Object, so why do you want it to pretend to be an array in JSON?

Comment: now I have changed the code. No objects. I have used the ArrayList<Double>, then I used GSON but now the array is conveted to a String, I dont want that

Answer (score 16):

**This code:**

```
JSONObject PED = new JSONObject();
PED.put( "fun", "enviarPedido" );
PED.put( "txtUser", "123" );
PED.put( "md5Passwd", "123" );

JSONArray articulos1 = new JSONArray();
articulos1.put( 50 );
articulos1.put( 10 );
articulos1.put( 5 );
articulos1.put( 50 );

JSONArray articulos2 = new JSONArray();
articulos2.put( 51 );
articulos2.put( 9 );
articulos2.put( 6.5 );
articulos2.put( 58.5 );

JSONArray articulos3 = new JSONArray();
articulos3.put( 52 );
articulos3.put( 8 );
articulos3.put( 7 );
articulos3.put( 56 );

JSONArray articulos4 = new JSONArray();
articulos4.put( 51 );
articulos4.put( 9 );
articulos4.put( 6.5 );
articulos4.put( 58.5 );

JSONArray arrArticulos = new JSONArray();
arrArticulos.put( articulos1 );
arrArticulos.put( articulos2 );
arrArticulos.put( articulos3 );
arrArticulos.put( articulos4 );

PED.put( "arrArticulos", arrArticulos );

JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
body.put( "PED", PED );

String json = body.toString();
```

**Will generate this string:**

```
{
    "PED": {
        "arrArticulos": [
            [
                50,
                10,
                5,
                50
            ],
            [
                51,
                9,
                6.5,
                58.5
            ],
            [
                52,
                8,
                7,
                56
            ],
            [
                51,
                9,
                6.5,
                58.5
            ]
        ],
        "md5Passwd": "123",
        "txtUser": "123",
        "fun": "enviarPedido"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do reverse engineering. Parse your Json String into a `Map<String,Object>` and that is the map that will give you your Json String if you use some Json library to write it as Json. You can use Json Jackson library or Gson library or any other available. Here is the code That I wrote to do what I just recommended:

```
private static void jsonParserTest() {
    try {
        String jsonStr = "{\n" +
                "    \"PED\": {\n" +
                "        \"fun\": \"enviarPedido\",\n" +
                "        \"txtUser\":\"123\",\n" +
                "        \"md5Passwd\": \"123\",                          \n" +
                "        \"arrArticulos\": [\n" +
                "            [50,10,5,50],\n" +
                "            [51,9,6.5,58.5],\n" +
                "            [52,8,7,56],\n" +
                "            [53,7,8.5,59.5]\n" +
                "        ]\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "}";
        Map<String, Object> map = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(jsonStr, Map.class);
        System.out.println(map);
        System.out.println(JsonUtils.writeObjectToJsonString(map));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
{PED={fun=enviarPedido, txtUser=123, md5Passwd=123, arrArticulos=[[50, 10, 5, 50], [51, 9, 6.5, 58.5], [52, 8, 7, 56], [53, 7, 8.5, 59.5]]}}
{"PED":{"fun":"enviarPedido","txtUser":"123","md5Passwd":"123","arrArticulos":[[50,10,5,50],[51,9,6.5,58.5],[52,8,7,56],[53,7,8.5,59.5]]}}
```

So if you create a Map that is described in the first line of an output and then serialize it as JSON you will get your desired JSON
The class JsonUtils used in my sample is a very thin wrapper over Json-Jackson library, but it is very simple to use. It is part of an open source MgntUtils library that is written and maintained by me. Here is a [Javadoc for JsonUtils class](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). The MgntUtils library if you want to use it can be found as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) on Maven central or On [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (with source code and Javadoc)